# node.js and generating modules at/during runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, runtime, dynamically-generated

I'm currently working on a node.js project that requires generating and altering objects in memory at and during runtime.  I know this sounds confusing, so here's an example.

Monday 10am:

```
var PI = Math.PI;

exports.area = function (r) {
   return PI * r * r;
};
```

Monday 11am:

```
var PI = Math.PI;
var minSize = 10;

exports.area = function (r) {
   if (r >= minSize) {
      return PI * r * r;
   } else {
      return "Error: Minimum size not met.";
   }
};
```

Monday 12noon:

```
var PI = Math.PI;
var minSize = 10;
var msg = "Error: Minimum size of " + minSize + "not met.";    

exports.area = function (r) {
   if (r >= minSize) {
      return PI * r * r;
   } else {
      return msg;
   }
};
```

Tuesday 10am:

```
var PI = Math.PI;
var minSize = 15;
var error['eng'] = "Error: Minimum size of " + minSize + "not met.";    
var error['chn'] = "錯誤：不符合最小尺寸:" + minSize + "。"    

exports.area = function (r) {
   if (r >= minSize) {
      return PI * r * r;
   } else {
      return error;
   }
};

exports.circumference = function (r) {
   if (r >= minSize) {
      return 2 * PI * r;
   } else {
      return error;
   }
};
```

---

This is a bit of a contrived example, because most of the changes could avoided with proper planning, I know, but it sort of goes to illustrate the point.  This module kept changing in both variables and functions, expanding while the server is running.

Here are the restrictions I have:

- Use Prototypal Inheritance (no keyword "new")
- Changes take effect at the next call of the function
- Changes include addition of new variables and functions
- Changes need to be saved for server restarts
- Cannot use eval()

I've thought of two possible strategies:

1. Using .prototype, continue to add/change functions and variables.

   - Pros: Able to do it as the server is running
   - Cons: I'm not sure how to save it to file.  As far as I know, I cannot save functions to file without using eval() in some way
2. Editing the files directly and reloading them through something like [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor).

   - Pros: Changes would be saved over, versions could be saved and reverted back to
   - Cons: I think editing the files directly would more or less have the same consequence using eval(), ie, if someone sneaks something malicious the system could break.

That's all I can think of right now.  Would appreciate any opinions or options in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

- [node.js' vm module](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) has several [runInContext()](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinthiscontext_code_filename) functions that will effectively sandbox the execution and prevent access to variables outside its scope. There is [a blog entry here](http://www.davidmclifton.com/2011/08/18/node-js-virtual-machine-vm-usage/) that discusses the difference between the different versions, with benchmarks available
- There is also a [sandbox](http://gf3.github.com/sandbox/) module available for node.js
- The disadvantage of running things in a sandbox is that the execution is a lot slower

Conclusion: It's not impossible to store functions and execute them safely within the confines of a sandbox, it's just not very practical.

Alternate Solution: If the functions themselves are not too complex, it's not impossible to store the calls in the form of a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and parse them back out after.